# Create View - access to success_url from templates

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

say I have:

```
class MyCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blabla')
    form_class = MyForm
```

And suppose in my template I want to add a `back` button. The back will lead me to the same page as `success_url`. My solution was to override `get_context_data` in `MyCreate` class and add `{'back': self.get_success_url()}` to the `context`.

The implications is that I have more CreateViews and I had to create a `ContextMixin` for this `back` button. Is there any other easier solution? something like accessing `success_url` directly in my template?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see in django (1.7) implementation of [`ContextMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L24), we must have access to `view` instance from our templates:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if 'view' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['view'] = self
    return kwargs
```

So you can access to success_url in templates:

```
{{ view.get_success_url }}
```

Comment: But 1.6 [also has](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L24) such code. And [even 1.5](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L23)

Answer (score 1):

In my case using **Django 1.10.3** the way to get it working was like this:

view:

```
from django.urls.base import reverse_lazy

class FooCreateView(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name-of-some-view')
```

template:

```
{{ view.success_url }}
```

The try of using `{{ view.get_success_url }}` was leading to:

`AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__dict__'`